# Old, experienced soldier in US slang

Tags: american-english, slang

In British slang, an "old sweat" is an old, experienced soldier. What is the American equivalent? I don't mean a veteran (someone who's left the military), I mean someone still in service.

Comment: Quite litterary, a "grognard" is an old soldier (*from the French word designating soldiers of Napoleon's Old Guard*).

Comment: "Old Guard" is sometimes used.

Comment: This question requires research to prove that "veteran" is the wrong answer. The question states that it means "someone who has left the military", but a quick look on dictionary.com shows that it just means someone who has been in a war, not that they no longer serve in forces. It even includes the phrase "veteran troops" as meaning experienced troops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term ***"[war horse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/war--horse)"*** or "***old war horse***" is often used to refer to an aged, experienced soldier.

> - (Informal) a veteran, as a soldier or politician, of many struggles and conflicts.

(Dictionary.refeence.com)

Answer (score 1):

Soldiers who yearn for the civilian life refer to such as "lifers."

Comment: A Lifer is someone with an intent to never quit the military.  You can have that intent at age 9.

Comment: @CandiedOrange \ Perhaps you come from a different walk of life than I do. I have never witnessed a nine-year-old being called, or referred to as, a lifer! I thank you for your opinion.

Comment: Well when you're 9 it's hard to get people to take you seriously.  Doesn't mean you're wrong. :)